# Как лучше изменить запрос

Tags: c#, asp.net

Здравствуйте. Существует следующий действующий запрос:

```
var query = from c in entity.Character
                        join g in entity.GuildMember
                        on c.Name equals g.Name
                        orderby c.MasterResetCount, c.ResetCount, c.cLevel
                        select new { c.Name, c.cLevel, c.ResetCount, c.MasterResetCount, c.Class, guildName = g.G_Name };
            var data = query.ToList();
```

Спустя время понадобилось его немного изменить (начали перетягивать модули с .php сайта). В старом сайте практически этот же запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
// Получаем список
            $Result = $DB2->Query('SELECT memb___id FROM MEMB_STAT WHERE ConnectStat = 1 order by ConnectTM ASC');

            // Если пусто
            if ($DB2->NumRows($Result) == 0) {
                echo '<tr><td colspan="6"><center>'.$Lang['RANKINGS_NULL'].'</center></td></tr>';
            }

// Информация о пользователях
            while($Info = $DB2->FetchArray($Result)) {
                ++$Count;

// Информация о персонаже
                $GetNick = $DB2->FetchRow($DB2->Query("SELECT GameIDC FROM AccountCharacter WHERE Id = '$Info[0]'"));
                $GetInfo = $DB2->FetchRow($DB2->Query("SELECT Name,Class,cLevel,ResetCount,MasterResetCount,MapNumber FROM Character WHERE Name = '$GetNick[0]'"));
                $Name = $GetInfo[0];
                $Class = $Engine->GetCharClass($GetInfo[1],0);
                $Level = $GetInfo[2];
                $ResetCount = $GetInfo[3]; 
                $MasterResetCount = $GetInfo[4]; 

// Выводим
                $Color = $Count % 2 ? 'charoffline' : 'charonline';
                echo '<tr class="'.$Color.'">
                        <td align="center">'.$Count.'</td>
                        <td align="center"><a href="char/'.$SelectedServer.'/'.$Name.'">'.$Name.'</a></td>
                        <td align="center">'.$Class.'</td>
                        <td align="center">'.$Level.'</td>
                        <td align="center">'.$ResetCount.'</td>
                        <td align="center">'.$MasterResetCount.'</td>
                    </tr>';
            }
```

То есть нам нужно получить весь список c.Name у которых в таблице MEMB_STAT значение ConnectStat = 1.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше поправить первый запрос для достижения нужного результата.

Comment: В `Linq` тоже есть фильтр `where`.

Comment: Не сомневаюсь). Вопрос в том, как лучше изменить данный запрос.

Comment: А при чем тут ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой запрос получился

```
var query = from c in entity.Character
            join g in entity.GuildMember 
            on c.Name equals g.Name into guild
            from guildWithNull in guild.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join ac in entity.AccountCharacter
            on c.Name equals ac.GameIDC
            join ms in entity.MEMB_STAT
            on ac.Id equals ms.memb___id
            where ms.ConnectStat == 1
            orderby c.MasterResetCount, c.ResetCount, c.cLevel
            select new { c.Name, c.cLevel, c.ResetCount, c.MasterResetCount, 
                         c.Class, guildName = guildOrNull.G_Name, connectTM = ms.ConnectTM };

var data = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Запрос сработал и получили требуемый результат. Очередной раз спасибо! Вопрос решился.